# How to access map function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is my controller code:

```php
public function RentCertificate()
{
    $report = Report::distric()->status(1)->desk(15)->get()
        ->groupBy(function (Report $item) {
            return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
        })
        ->map(function($rows, $key) {
            return [
                'column_one' => $rows->column_one,
                'rows' => $rows
            ];
        });

    return view('adcr.report.rent_certificate', compact('report'));
}
```

when I try

```xml
@foreach($report as $key => $data)
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="input_bangla">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->fiscal_year }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->month }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I got:

> Property [fiscal_year] does not exist on this collection instance.

How can I access this data?

Comment: The real question is why would you do this call to `map()` in the first place? You're just needlessly making things complicated.

Comment: @miken32 please show me how can I do it easily? I'm very new in laravel so I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```xml
@foreach($report as $key => $data)
```

`$data` is the array you've mapped. An array like `['column_one' => ..., 'rows' => ...]`, it's **not** an object. You need to access one of its keys (`column_one` or `rows`).

Also, you can use a ternary operator with loop iteration to assign the classes `even` or `odd` in your `<tr>` element.

---

```xml
@foreach($report as $key => $data)
    <tr role="row" class="{{ ($loop->iteration % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd' }}">
        <td class="input_bangla">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data['rows']->fiscal_year }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data['rows']->month }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: sir I also try this method by I got same result  ```@foreach($report as $key=>$data)
<tr role="row" class="{{ ($loop->iteration % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd' }}">
<td class="input_bangla">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
<td>{{ $data['rows']->fiscal_year }}</td>
<td>{{ $data['rows']->month }}</td>```

Comment: @miken32 now i got Undefined index: fiscal_year (View: C:\wamp64\www\report-management\resources\views\adcr\report\rent_certificate.blade.php)

Comment: @miken32 not really. `$rows` is an object. @John try doing `dd($report->first())` before `return view(....)`. Can you edit your question with the dumped information?

Comment: Ah of course that's right